# Turbo C ERRORS "declaration is not allowed here" (struct and file operations)

Tags: c, file, struct

```
struct student{
  int number;
  char name[20];
  char surname[20];
 float exam1;
 float exam2;
 float exam3;
 float homework1;
 float homework2;
 float average;
};
```

Here's the struct I wrote:

```
struct student a;
```

When I want to use that struct in another function, I get this error:"declaration is not allowed here"

```
FILE *dg= fopen("student.txt","w");
```

or

```
FILE *dg;
[dg= fopen("student.txt","w");
```

Also the same error occurs when I try to open a file.
Sorry for my English, I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I see no usage of `student` in your examples... Also, you should show some context for them.

Comment: First: Turbo C is not a good compiler - you need to get a better compiler - There are many free ones.  Secondly: the lines where you open the file have nothing to do with the struct - we will need to see all the code.

Comment: Probably you have some non-declaration statements before the line with the error

Comment: Try `gcc` or `clang`, they're free.

Comment: The `[` in `[dg= fopen("student.txt","w");` is erroneous — presumably, just a typo.  However, it would be better if you showed us an MCVE ([MCVE]).  But you're using a compiler that only accepts C90 — it won't allow variable declarations after the first executable statement in a block.  The error sounds like you're writing declarations after an executable statement.  But we shouldn't have to guess; you should be showing us the minimal code that reproduces the error.  You should also show the exact error message, with the line number that corresponds to the code you show.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code snippets you have written... so please **edit your question and provide a full, failing example** so we can get to the problem, that you have taken off from the code you present.  It is very importan you read the StackOverflow on how to post a good example, or we shall be  unable to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response,
I wrote them first line;

```
void stdu(){
    FILE *dg; 
    struct student a;
    dg= fopen("student.txt","w");
    functions();
        .
        .
    operations...
        .
        .
    fclose(dg);
}
```

old version

```
void stdu(){
   functions();
   FILE *dg= fopen("student.txt","w");
   struct student a;
        .
        .
    operations...
        .
        .
    fclose(dg);
}
```